# Clicking the Internet Explorer icon opens Google Chrome instead

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, browser, internet-explorer

Whenever I click on the Internet Explorer icon, it opens the Google Chrome web browser instead. However, if I right-click the Internet Explorer icon and select "Open New Tab", it will open Internet Explorer, which is fine.

How can I make it so that clicking on the Internet Explorer icon will launch Internet Explorer, and not Chrome?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question so that it's a bit more understandable so we could help you out. 

Are you saying that Chrome works but IE isn't opening correctly?

Comment: Could it be that the icon, on which you click, does start the default browser? Thus, setting the IE to your default browser might solve your problem?

Comment: translate to EN by google Point -3  OK ---- When  click on Internet Explorer, Chrome browser opens  -----  I did default browser IE, no fix

Comment: I rewrote the question and title to match what I believe what you wanted to say. The tags say you are using Windows 8.1 Is this in the Start Screen? You are clicking on the IE tile, right? Not a desktop icon? Can you provide screenshots to illustrate the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Default Browser means a internet shortcut file (.URL) would open in whichever browser you set as the default

Sounds like your Internet Explorer shortcut (.LNK) on your Desktop is bad or has the wrong path. You will need to right-click it & confirm the Shortcut tab has a Target (path) of: "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

Pay close attention to the file types/extensions (.LNK vs .URL) as you could have a internet shortcut file named `Internet Explorer.url` that consequently opens in the default browser of Chrome

Comment: Taskbar: right-click, right-click item (above Unpin), Properties

Answer (score 0):

Reset Internet Explorer

1. Reset Solution 1:

   - List item
   - Open Internet Explorer.
   - Click on Tools menu (Press “alt” key to active menu bar).
   - Click on “Internet Options“. A configuration window you will appear
   - Click on advanced tab.
   - Click on “Reset” Button. You’ll get an another box, here check a box
     named as “Delete Personal Settings“, then
   - Click on Reset button on it.
2. Reset Solution 2:

If you couldn’t open IE or you couldn’t reset Internet Explorer through above method, so there is another method which is very effective to reset Internet Explorer through control panel. Follow the following steps:

- Click on Start Button
- Click on Control panel
- Click on Network and Internet
- Click on “Internet Options“. (You will get a configuration window)
- Click on advanced tab.
- Click on “Reset” Button. You’ll get an another box, here check the box named as “Delete Personal Settings“, then click on Reset button on it.

  3. **If doesn’t fix**

  Run Microsoft Fixit’s

Download and run these Microsoft fixit to resolve that problem.
http://support.microsoft.com/mats/ie_freezes_or_crashes/
http://support.microsoft.com/mats/ie_performance_and_safety/

Restart the computer.